# photo chooser task windows phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, unhandled-exception

i need to take a picture from the directory of Windows phone in my application so i add a child Windows when i click on the text in this child Windows i add a button and i called

public partial class AnnotationControl : ChildWindow
    {

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> cercle { get; set; }
    public AnnotationControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }



    private void ChildWindow_Closing_1(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnsave_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
                   this.DialogResult = true;
    }



    private void btnCancel_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }



    private void browse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
PhotoChooserTask objPhotoChooser = new PhotoChooserTask();
                 objPhotoChooser.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(PhotoChooseCall);
                 objPhotoChooser.Show(); 
    }
```

but when i clicked on the button to choose a picture the application crashed 
"Application_UnhandledException"
some one have any idea please

Comment: try to debug using breakpiont to trace the exact exception.and also mention in which line of code it's crashes

Answer (score 0):

Use this may be helpful

```
    private void changeImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
        photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
        photoChooserTask.Show();
    }
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {

            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

            imageTapped.Source = bmp;

        }
    }
```